# Что ограничивает количество записей, возвращаемых MariaDB в запросах через C connector?

Tags: c++, mysql, c, mariadb

Как сделать, чтобы запрос SELECT возвращал полный набор строк, а не какое то ограниченное количество?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался самостоятельно. "Ограничение" было вызвано аномальной работой СУБД (скорее всего сбоем в индексах).